# How to append the variable value to the element using document.write

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append the variable value to the element

what i am doing is i am taking the input body onload by using javascript prompt.

now i am storing the input value to one variable.

now i want to append the variable value to this element

```
<a href="#" class="uname">Welcome User!</a>
```

in place of welcome user,i want to get the input variable value.

here is the code i am using..

```
function inpt(){
    var person=prompt("Please enter your name","");
    if (person!=null && person!="")
      {
        document.write(person);
      }
}
```

How can i do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a href="#" id="uname" class="uname">Welcome User!</a>
```

**js**

```
function inpt(){
    var person=prompt("Please enter your name","")
        uname = document.getElementById("uname");

    if (person!=null && person!="")
      {
        uname.innerHTML = 'Welcome '+person+ '!'
        //document.write(person);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first in my opinion you should give the link an id. eg.

```
<a href="#" class="uname" id="uname">Welcome User!</a>
```

then instead of writing

```
document.write(person);
```

you should use

```
document.getElementById('uname').innerHTML = person;
```

hope that helps.

Comment: It might be worth saying that you CANNOT use `document.write` to manipulate existing DOM elements. A `document.write` after page load will destroy the current DOM and create a new one

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function inpt(){
var person=prompt("Please enter your name","");
if (person!=null && person!="")
  {
    $('.uname').html(person);
  }
 }
```

Comment: you are assuming he is using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript Window.onload function which is fired when the entire page loads.

Javscript code:

```
 <script>
window.onload=function(){
 var person=prompt("Please enter your name","");
 if (person!=null && person!="")
  {
    $("#uname").append(person);
  }
}

</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<a href="#"  id="uname">Welcome</a>
```